# Ckeditor and IMCE not working with Plupload

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, files, media

When I use IMCE with CKeditor as a WYSIWYG for my website it works fine:
[image]

However when I add the [Plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload) module which would allow me multiple files selection it breaks!

[image]

If this can't be fixed, is there any other alternatives similar to Plupload that I can use with CKeditor?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert) module instead of IMCE

> Insert is a utility that makes inserting images and links to files
>   into text areas or WYSIWYGs much easier. It adds a simple
>   JavaScript-based button to FileField and ImageField widgets. When used
>   with ImageField and ImageCache, images may be inserted into text areas
>   with a specific ImageCache preset.

Comment: I will give it a try - can you upload multiple files with this? If not I can always just continue using IMCE as it has a much nicer UI

Comment: yes you can upload multiple files

Answer (score 0):

Check the module [IMCE Uploader](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce_uploader). It depends on IMCE and Plupload.

> Besides that, It also provides the Plupload uploader as a plugin (in
>   this module) to allow uploading multiple files at a time. If you want
>   to use it, just select "IMCE Uploader - Plupload" the module list and
>   enable it